# script that to find the sum of multiples of 3 in array - Python script question

Tags: python

Currently working with this script snippet:

```
values = [1, 3, "5", 7, 8, 9]
multiples_of_three = []
total_of_threes = 0

#find 3s
while not (i > values. length):
    if (values[i] % 3):
        multiples_of_three[i] = values[i]

#do sum
while True:
    if not multiples_of_three.empty():
        total_of_threes = total_of_threes + multiples_of_three.first_item
        multiples_of_three.remove_first_item
    elif multiples_of_three.empty():
        break

print(total_of_threes)
```

and running into error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Any idea on how this could be solved?

Comment: What is the variable `i` supposed to be?  You haven't defined any variable of that name.

Comment: NONE of this is valid Python - are you sure you're reading the right textbook???  Lists don't have a `length` attribute (use the `len()` function instead), nor `empty`, `first_item`, or `remove_first_item`...

Comment: I'm attempting to write up a script that to find the sum of multiples of 3 in array. I will update the script

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://<sitename>.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to declare your i variable before using it

```
values = [1, 3, "5", 7, 8, 9]
multiples_of_three = []
total_of_threes = 0
i = 0
```

anyway, you should check your code, you are trying to use methods that doesnt exist.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple incoherences in your code (missing variable definitions, inexistent methods...). In addition, the style is not that of python, you wouldn't use a `while` loop to iterate over elements of a list.

A pythonic approach would be to use a list comprehension.

Here an example for python ≥ 3.8:

```
values = [1, 3, "5", 7, 8, 9]

out = sum(i for x in values if (i:=int(x))%3 == 0)
```

Output: `12`

If you want to ignore strings:

```
out = sum(x for x in values
          if isinstance(x, (int, float))
          and x%3 == 0)
```